# Symfony2: performance with form creation

Tags: forms, performance, symfony

I have a system that generates forms dynamically with Symfony2. It works fine with little forms, but when I have collection of hundreds of elements then it may take up to 10s to generate the page.

Looking in the profiler, a lot of time is spent doing $form->createView() (more than 5s in debug mode). As Symfony2 processes fields like forms in a recursive way, I think that there might be a lot a processing for a single fields, but can that not be optimized ?

I noticed another strange behavior with 'choice' fields: with huge collections, the more values there are, the more time it takes (I tested it by limiting to 0, 1, 2, all values). ???

I can't show all parts of the code (too big), but some parts if needed.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure the Form component was created with your use case in mind. If no answer comes, I think you might want to read the code of the component and rewrite the view creation part in particular to fit your needs. I'm afraid I personnally can't help you with that.
Also, who is the poor will have to go through hundreds of form fields? :p

Comment: "the more values there are, the more time it takes" - and it should be the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is not suited for symfony forms. Simple as that.

Generete the inputs by hand, submit every collection entry via ajax, etc.